# Macros to import multi-column data from Google spreadsheets to auto trigger mails

Tags: email, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

How to use macros to import multi-column data from Google spreadsheets to auto trigger mails using sendEmails ? I tried tweaking the code given in google for one column containing a single alphabetic message.

function sendEmails() 
{ var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); var startColumn = 2; var numColumns = 6; var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startColumn, 1, numColumns, 4); var data = dataRange.getValues(); for (var i in data) 
{ var Column = data[i]; var emailAddress = Column[0]; var Sl_No = Column[1]; var Insured_Name =Column[2]; var Policy_No = Column[3]; var subject = ('Sending emails from a Spreadsheet'); MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, (Sl_No,Insured_Name,Policy_No)); } } –

Comment: Also add the code that you "tried tweaking"

Comment: function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startColumn = 2; 
  var numColumns = 6; 
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startColumn, 1, numColumns, 4);
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i in data) {
    var Column = data[i];
    var emailAddress = Column[0]; 
    var Sl_No = Column[1]; 
    var Insured_Name =Column[2]; 
    var Policy_No = Column[3]; 
    var subject = ('Sending emails from a Spreadsheet');
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, (Sl_No,Insured_Name,Policy_No));
    
  }
}

Comment: Edit your question and add that code.